# Trying to run ECS Task using airflow scheduler

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run ECS task with the help of airflow scheduler. Just using the example template with few changes.
But my task is running indefinitely when i execute DAG manually from airflow webserver UI.

```
import datetime
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import EcsRunTaskOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="ecs_fargate_dag",
    default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email": ["airflow@example.com"],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
    },
    default_view="graph",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    tags=["example"],
)
# generate dag documentation
dag.doc_md = __doc__

# [START howto_operator_ecs]
hello_world = EcsRunTaskOperator(
    task_id="space",
    dag=dag,
    cluster="Lab",
    task_definition="<MY TASK DEFINITION ARN>",
    launch_type="FARGATE",
    overrides={
        "containerOverrides": [
            {
                "name": "space",
                "command": ["<ENTRYPOINT COMMAND>"],
            },
        ],
    },
    network_configuration={
        "awsvpcConfiguration": {
            "securityGroups": [os.environ.get("SECURITY_GROUP_ID", "sg-123abc")],
            "subnets": [os.environ.get("SUBNET_ID", "subnet-123456ab")],
        },
    },
    tags={
        "Customer": "X",
        "Project": "Y",
        "Application": "Z",
        "Version": "0.0.1",
        "Environment": "Development",
    },
    awslogs_group="/ecs/hello-world",
    awslogs_stream_prefix="prefix_b/hello-world-container",  # prefix with container name
)
# [END howto_operator_ecs]
```

Please help me figure out if i am missing something.
I have AWS configured in my localhost machine.

Comment: All Airflow is doing is starting the task. If the task isn't exiting on its own then it will continue running indefinitely. What is running in the task, and why do you expect it to not run indefinitely?

Comment: my task just triggers a sagemaker pipeline and shuts down immediately after that

Comment: If your task shuts down on its own, then what exactly is running indefinitely?

Comment: my task on ecs cluster shuts down on its own but the Dag task on airflow keeps on running. Problem was the missing package required by the airflow Dag.

Comment: You really needed to be more explicit in your original question and explain it was the DAG task, not the ECS task.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the cause. The packages required by the airflow task code was missing. It made the task appear to run indefinitely on the UI without giving any error.
pip installed required provider and ran the DAG again. works fine now!